# What is the syntax of for loops in java?

Tags: java

Why does this statement give me an error in the program mentioned below?
    for(int y=0, int z=0; z

The program I used it in is ::

```
class Testloops
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int[] x={ 7,6,5,2,8,9,3};
          for(int y=0, int z=0; z<x.length;z++)
          {
              y= x[z];
              System.out.println(y+ " ");
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the second `int` declaration.

```
for (int y = 0, z = 0; z < x.length; z++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, remove the `int` type before `z=0`, then it will work!

`for(int y=0, z=0; z < x.length ;z++)`

Answer (score 0):

You only need the first `int`, see a working example here:

http://ideone.com/wGDCIE

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

- Declare Y outside the for statement

  ```
   int y = 0; 
   int[] x={ 7,6,5,2,8,9,3};

   for (int z=0;z<x.length;z++)
   {
        y= x[z];
        System.out.println(y+ " ");
    }
  ```

Not sure why you are declaring y inside the for statement, as its not being iterated?

Comment: Reason might be so that the scope of `y` is limited to the `for` loop.